# Calculating the average temperature in a week. Python

Tags: python

I am a new coder and was wondering if anybody could tell me what was going wrong with the code below. I was trying to answer the question below and have been stuck. If anybody could help that would be awesome.

> Write a program that asks the user to enter the high temperature for
>   each day of one week. Store the temperatures in a list. Once
>   completed, output all temperatures that have been stored into the list
>   as a formatted table along with the average temperature for the week.

```
week_days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

print "Day" + (" "*12) + "High Temperature"
print "-"*30
temperature = []
temp = 0
spaces = 0

for i in range (len(week_days)):
    temp_input = input ("Enter the temperature for" +week_days[i]+str(":"))
    temperature.append(temp_input)
    spaces = 15-len(week_days[i])
    print week_days[i]," "*spaces,temperature[i]

avg= 0
list_sum = 0 
for i in range (len(temperature)):
    avg = ((list_sum + temperature[i])-15)/7
    avg = int((avg*100) + 0.5)/100
print "The average temperature for this week is", average
```

EDIT: Sorry guys I fixed the error, but now my average only seems to be printing 3. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so, please [edit] your question and include the full text of them. Please also show some example input and your expected and actual output.

Comment: sum is inbuilt function in python, use variable other than sum, what have you stored in sum??

Answer (score 0):

- Sum is in-built function, it's used to calculate the the sum of elements inside a list. not sure what you wanna calculate, but if you wanna calculate the sum of temperatures, you can use it this way `sum(temperature)`
- Try to add convert inputs to int to apply math operations

Would be better if you can give more details. But your code should look like:

```
week_days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

print "Day" + (" "*12) + "High Temperature"
print "-"*30
temperature = []
temp = 0
spaces = 0

for i,x in enumerate(week_days):
    temp_input = input ("Enter the temperature for" +x+str(":"))
    temperature.append(int(temp_input))
    spaces = 15-len(x)
    print x," "*spaces,temperature[i]

avg= sum(temperature)//len(week_days)


print "The average temperature for this week is", avg
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict with [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format), you can pass the keys as args and use [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to output the data any way you want:

```
week_days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]

# get user input for each day and convert to ints
temps  = map(int,[raw_input("Enter temp for {}".format(week_days[i])) for i in xrange(7)])
# make dict with days as keys and temps as values
zipped = dict(zip(week_days,temps))

print("Daily Temps:  Monday: {Mon} Tuesday: {Tue} Wednesday: {Wed}"
      " Thursday: {Thu} Friday: {Fri} Saturday: {Sat} Sunday: {Sun}".format(**zipped))

 print("Average Temp for the week: {:.2f}".format(sum(temps) / 7.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this following simple code:

```
day1 = input("enter mondays temp: ")

day2 = input("enter tuesdays temp: ")

day3 = input("enter wednesdays temp: ")

day4 = input("enter thursdays temp: ")

day5 = input("enter fridays temp: ")

day6 = input("enter saturdays temp: ")

day7 = input("enter sundays temp: ")

av = (day1+day2+day3+day4+day5+day6+day7) / 7


print("The average temperature is ",av)
```

Comment: It's true that this does calculate the average, but this really doesn't help the OP